# How to sync between animation event and moving object at the animation event time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

The problem is that the object that move in the animation event time is not smoothly start moving with the animation but there is some kind of a delay and then the object start moving.

It's happening when the child object get released from the player hand at the event time.
I recorded a short video of the unity editor showing the problem at second 39-40.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjaolcHL8Vo

This code is attached to the player with the animator controller and the animation event

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ThrowObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public MoveToTarget moveToTarget;

    public void ThrowEvent()
    {
        moveToTarget.go = true;
    }
}
```

And this code is attached to the child object in the player hand and make the child object to start moving when the ThrowEvent happens. I'm using animation curve and lerp because I wanted to make the child object moving with ease out/in but I also tried it with just simple vector3 movetowards and in both cases I tried to start moving the child object with higher speed value but it didn't solve the releasing problem of the child object from the player hand at the animation event. it looks like a delay of the releasing.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Cinemachine;

public class Moving : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum TransitionState
    {
        None,
        MovingTowards,
        MovingBackward
    }

    public Transform destinationTransform;
    public bool isChild = false;
    public AnimationCurve curve = AnimationCurve.EaseInOut(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    public float duration = 10.0f;
    public bool go = false;
    public Text[] debbugingUiTexts;
    public Transform parentPos;

    private float t;
    private TransitionState state = TransitionState.MovingTowards;
    private Vector3 originPosition;
    private SphereCollider col;
    private bool enableCollider = true;
    private bool updateOriginPosition = true;
    private float rounded;
    private float durationCounter;

    void Start()
    {
        t = 0.0f;

        curve.postWrapMode = WrapMode.Once;
        col = GetComponent<SphereCollider>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        var v1 = destinationTransform.position - transform.position;
        if (v1.magnitude < 0.01f)
        {
            t = 0.0f;
            originPosition = transform.position;
            state = TransitionState.MovingBackward;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B))
        {
            t = 0.0f;
            originPosition = transform.position;
            state = TransitionState.MovingBackward;
        }

        if (go)
        {
            transform.parent = null;

            if (updateOriginPosition == true)
            {
                originPosition = transform.position;
                updateOriginPosition = false;
            }

            if (col != null && enableCollider)
            {
                Destroy(col);
                enableCollider = false;
            }

            switch (state)
            {
                case TransitionState.MovingTowards:

                    t += Time.deltaTime;
                    float s = t / duration;

                    durationCounter += Time.deltaTime;
                    rounded = Mathf.Round(durationCounter);
                    debbugingUiTexts[0].text = rounded.ToString();

                    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(originPosition,
                        destinationTransform.position, curve.Evaluate(s));

                    break;

                case TransitionState.MovingBackward:

                    if (transform.position != parentPos.position)
                    {
                        t += Time.deltaTime;
                        float s1 = t / duration;

                        durationCounter += Time.deltaTime;
                        rounded = Mathf.Round(durationCounter);
                        debbugingUiTexts[0].text = rounded.ToString();

                        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(originPosition,
                            parentPos.position,
                            curve.Evaluate(s1));
                    }

                    break;

                default:
                    this.enabled = false;
                    return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What might be happening is that your current animation has to finnish first before transitioning. To make it smoother uncheck Has Exit Time on your transition (click on the line between animation states to do this.)

Comment: @MrMoonMan there is no transition. in the animator controller this state with the throw animation is the default so when i'm running the game it's playing this animation only, like in the youtube video.

Comment: @MrMoonMan i forgot to mention that the player throwing animation is taken from mixamo.com and the animation is humanoid and i also tried to set the root motion to false/true by script already.

Comment: Ok, i found that if I increase the animation of throwing to be faster for example in the state in the animator controller i change the speed from 1 to 2 and the movement of the transform to be faster too then it's working fine and nice.  the problem still exist when the animation speed is in it's default value 1. because I want to make the throw to be a bit like a slow motion effect and not throwing it too fast like throwing a stone.  it's more like sending the transform away to a target not throwing it.  I called it throwing but it should be more like "send" the transform to "fly" to target.